# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freezes on shutting down (mouse disappears and everything hangs)

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, shutdown

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04) on a Lenovo IdeaPad 720S (possibly relevant is that it has an Nvidia GeForce MX150 2GB) and it is now unable to shutdown or switch to tty. Every time I try either command the mouse disappears and the system hangs until I do a hard shutdown. I installed the nvidia-390 drivers and am up to date on everything, so I really don't know what's going on...

(apologies for formatting -- pretty new here, if someone could let me know how to fix this post I will)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all the Nvidia drivers instead. Lots of people reporting similar problems with recent updates.

I've tried new kernels(4.17.17) and latest Nvidia drivers and couldn't make it work either.